# How to add Click Handler through reference of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React js and want know that, it is possible to add click handler through reference of component.

I tried following but it didn't work

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class RefsDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.inputRef=React.createRef();
    this.buttonRef=React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
      console.log(this.buttonRef);
      this.buttonRef.current.onClick=()=>this.abchandle()
  }

  abchandle()
  {
      alert('hi');
  }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button ref={this.buttonRef} >click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.buttonRef.current` is a DOM node, not a react component, so to define the on click handler, you should define the `onclick` (note the lower case `c`) instead:
`this.buttonRef.current.onclick=()=>this.abchandle()`

https://codepen.io/liboul/pen/jRJmqZ

Answer (score 1):

I believe we need to pick the node using ref and then add an event listner like this -:

We need to import 'react-dom' to make it work

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

Then add this piece of code -:

```
componentDidMount()
  {
      let domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.buttonRef.current);
      if(domNode) {
        domNode.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));
      }
  }
```

Hope it helps.... BTW why do we need to attach click handler when we can do something like this in the JSX

```
<button onClick={() => console.log('click')} >Click</button>
```

Can see this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zakgqb?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is achievable through the onClick attribute and this is the best practice to implement this task.

so inside the button element just add an onClick attribute like this:

```
<button onClick={this.abchandle}>click</button>
```

There is no reason to use add an event listener for this, this is not the react way.